# Use XPath to match with regex separate nodes into an array

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a block of html like this:

```
<div class="address ellipsis ab-address-text ab-address-margin-c1" data-label="property-address">
            <a href="/realestateandhomes-detail/2021-N-52nd-Ave_Hollywood_FL_33021_M58338-85481">

                <span class="listing-street-address">
                  2021 N 52nd Ave,
                  </span>
                  <span class="listing-city">Hollywood</span>,
                  <span class="listing-region">FL</span>
                  <span class="listing-postal">33021</span>
            </a>
          </div>
```

The page is full of the same structure, just the actual text node values will change, e.g. instead of 20221 N 52 Ave, it could be 1234 Main St,

I can successfully use XPath to grab all the addresses, city, state, zip on page, which is what I want:

```
$x('//div[contains(@class,"address")]/a//child::text()')
```

The problem is it returns a single array of text nodes:

```
(394) [text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, …]
```

It would be ideal to return addresses, city, state zip as an array of strings, so that I wouldn't have to use regex to split the string. For example:

["2021 N 52nd Ave, Hollywood FL 33021", ...]

Is there a way to achieve this with XPath?

Comment: You're doing this "live" in the page, right? Why not write a Javascript loop that iterates over the parent objects and extracts exactly what you want as you want it? Alternatively, you could just parse the `href` URL, which has the address in it.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 doesn't have a rich enough set of data types, but it's easily done in later versions. In fact, you might well want to move more of the processing from Javascript into XPath - but that depends on what you are actually doing with the data once you find it.

With XPath 3.1 (available from Javascript using the Saxon-JS library) you could do

```
//div[contains-token(@class, 'address')] ! span ! array{string(.)}
```

which returns a sequence of arrays, each containing the fields of one address.

Disclaimer: Saxon-JS is my product.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple addresses on your webpage, you can probably loop over the div elements, get all the the texts descendant of the anchor element with `normalize-space` and store the result in a list. Something like :

```
var result = [];
var els = document.evaluate("//div[contains(@class,'address')]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
        
for (var i=0 ; i < els.snapshotLength; i++)
{
   result.push(document.evaluate('normalize-space(./a)', els.snapshotItem(i), null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue);
}
```

Output of the `normalize-space` on your sample data :

```
2021 N 52nd Ave, Hollywood, FL 33021
```